# How to specify a maximum amount of time a program can run in C++

Tags: c++, linux, macos

In my C++ program, I will start other programs with exec. However, I want to be able to specify a maximum amount of time that the programs can run. How can that be done?

Is setrlimit the right thing to use?

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a brute-force version, but... save/get the handle of the started programm/process, start a timer and kill the other process after the timer has expired?

Comment: How do I get the handle when using execv?

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions that comes to mind.

1- Send the duration to the second program via the command line and manage the duration internally in the 2nd exe.
2- Create a timer in the first exe and when the timer is triggered kill the 2nd process.

Max.

Comment: Of course, the first version only works if you yourself have written the other app.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it can't be done using standard c++ - you will have to use whatever scheduling functions your operating system (which you haven't specified) provides.

Comment: I'm using OSX, which is like Linux.